# Disabling the checkbox in angular directive template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-directive

I have the directive shown below that displays a checkbox in cells of a table:

```
app.directive('csSelect', function () {
    return {
        template: '<input ng-model="checked" ng-click="csFunc()" disabled="isDisabled" type="checkbox"/>',
        scope: {
            row: '=csSelect',
            csFunc: '&csFunc',
            isDisabled: '=csDisabled'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

            scope.$watch('checked', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue === true) {
                    element.parent().addClass('st-selected');
                } else {
                    element.parent().removeClass('st-selected');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

---

```
<td  cs-select="device" cs-func='selectRow(device.ItsRepairImeiListId)' cs-disabled="false" ></td>
```

---

The problem is that the `disabled` attribute is not working for some reason. Whatever value I provide, the checkbox is always disabled. I have tried using `@csDisabled` as well but no success.

Any ideas on what I should do get the checkbox disabled whenever I want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to assign scope value `disabled` attribute, for that you need to use `ng-disabled` directive instead of using only `disabled`.

```
template: '<input ng-model="checked" ng-click="csFunc()" ng-disabled="isDisabled" type="checkbox"/>',
```

Comment: Alright finally managed to get it working. Thank you so much for your time !

Comment: @Cemre Glad to help you..Thanks :)